# Running offline AJAX appliaction on Opera Mobile 11

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, mobile, opera

I'm preparing project for web application with large AJAX usage, which should work on Smartphones. One of requirements is that the application should be able to run without internet connection. The scenario when application is launched and then the internet connection is lost is relatively simple, but what in case the user have no internet connections, and wants to launch this application?

Opera Mobile has the ability to save the page, which could be loaded even without internet connections, the problem is however the fully AJAX application. I've checked 2 examples: [GWT-Ext Showcase](http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/) and [ZK Calendar Demo](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/application/zk_calendar), both of them running in online mode, but failed to launch in offline mode (blank screen, with no error message). I suppose the problem is the Opera saved the main page itself, but not the required JavaScript. In this fall I have question:

What should the developer do to make his web application running in Opera Mobile in offline mode? How should the JavaScript be organized to be downloaded by Opera for offline mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a [cache manifest file](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/).

You could also just paste all the javascript into the main html page (inline) (more difficult to do with images though)

Comment: Well, I see the idea, but GWT applications f.g. have by idea no caching for javascript files set. Caching would made the updates problematic, since javascript might not refresh. It would be optimal if the browser by itself would save all needed files for offline mode, and of course it will not try to refresh javascript resources where network connection is not available.

Comment: You could allow caching of JS, and use cache busting (src="test.js?v=2) in the html when the JS has changed.